# Customizing view modal popup in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

How I can increase the width of the view record dialog in jqgrid. I see there are currently options for edit or add case. Currently I'm doing through css, is there any nice way?

Vijaya Anand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The View form has some [properties](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties1) which can be used to change many dialog settings, like `width` for example. Default vlue of the `width` is 300.